pip install pygbag is not installing?
C:\Users\Hp>pip install pygbag
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.0.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.1.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.1.5 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.2.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.3.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.3.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.4.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.5.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.6.3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.6.4 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.6.5 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.6.6 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.7.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.7.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.7.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.8.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.8.1 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.8.2 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.8.3 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.8.4 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.8.5 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.8.6 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.9.0 Requires-Python >=3.8; 0.9.1 Requires-Python >=3.8
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygbag (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygbag

I tried to install pygbag in my cmd.
Could not install and was giving this error...
Help Please even after I install the latest version of python on my PC.
C:\Users\Yehoshu'a>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/6a/19e9fe04fca059ccf770861c7d5721ab4c2aebc539889e97c7977528a53b/pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.1MB 883kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
  The script pip3.10.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Yehoshu'a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-24.0


It requires python >=3.8 to install pygbag
Your python is 3.7 you need to upgrade your python.
https://pypi.org/project/pygbag/


Also, once you’ve installed the Python binaries You will either need to type the entire path, or add the installation directory to your system’s PATH variable.
Check this out for adding directory to PATH :
Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows
